# Decoding s3 file names having special characters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, boto3

while writing lambda code to copy one file from source to destination bucket I'm facing some issue. Getting cloudwatch logs specifying folder name as file_name

```
insidesource/newsource/test/Active%3D1/devopsnotes.txt
```

whereas my actual folder name contains `Active=1`

Please find logs from cloud watch and lambda code as well.
Need assistance on how to decode particular file name in cloudwatch logs.

[lambda code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zl7n.png)  and [cloudwatch logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lhwM.jpg)

Comment: There is no such thing as folders in S3, it's just something the AWS S3 UI is showing.
There are 2 entities, bucket name, and in every bucket there are multiple keys, where the key is the full path following the bucket name
for bucket "my bucket" and the key (filename) will be "/the/path/to/my/file.csv"

Comment: @meny will take care...

Answer (score 1):

The s3 object key names are URL encoded in cloudwatch logs.
Check out [Characters that might require special handling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html)
 for s3 object names.

You can use the [unquote_plus()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) from `urllib.parse` to get the decoded file name -

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

file_name = "insidesource/newsource/test/Active%3D1/devopsnotes.txt"
print(unquote_plus(file_name))
```

**Output:**

```
insidesource/newsource/test/Active=1/devopsnotes.txt
```

Comment: Note that the key is [urlencoded, with plus symbols for spaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html), so you'll need to use `unquote_plus` instead of `unquote`

Comment: Good point @AnonCoward, updated